# SQL how to make a job run a job?

Tags: sql, jobs

I'd like to call another job immediately after first one has finished, or to be more precise is it possible to call an entire sql job via a job step. I'd like to avoid merging these jobs into 1 so I wonder if this solution is possible?

Comment: similar question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31104/calling-a-sql-server-job-within-another-job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can execute a job by using this stored procedure. In your case, you can simply add a step to the end of your first job, to call the name of the job you want executed next.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Job Name';
```

See [sp_start_job (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

create a T-SQl Step and use `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'YourJob';`

Answer (score -1):

Call the Jobs in the order you wish from a stored procedure.